# Как удалить блок созданный в js?

Tags: javascript, функции

в HTML есть блок `<div id="containertt" style="width: 700px; height: 500px" class="container_wrp">` . Из первой функции, он удаляется.

```
let containerWRP = document.querySelector(".container_wrp");

jccBtnJap.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //удалям блок и создаем по новому и добавляем новый
    containerWRP.remove();
    let jccDiv = document.createElement('div');
    jccDiv.style.width = '700px';
    jccDiv.style.height = '500px';
    jccDiv.id = 'jap_container';
    jccDiv.classList.add('container_wrp');
    wrpBlock.appendChild(jccDiv);
    
  }
```

А вот со второй функции, когда я блок создаю уже динамически - он не удаляется, а просто создается рядом новый. Почему?
Вторая функция -

```
jccBars.addEventListener("click", function () {
    //удалям блок и создаем по новому и добавляем новый
    containerWRP.remove();
    let jccDiv = document.createElement('div');
    jccDiv.style.width = '700px';
    jccDiv.style.height = '500px';
    jccDiv.id = 'stick_container';
    jccDiv.classList.add('container_wrp');
    wrpBlock.appendChild(jccDiv);
  }
```

Comment: Называется: Найди 10 отличий :)

Comment: @EzioMercer , вы правы, в этом блоке кода, отличий почти нет. Кроме цвета, здесь только запрос идет и создание удаление элементов.

Comment: Цвета как раз таки одинаковые, а `id` отличаются)

Comment: @EzioMercer, в первом цвет у jccJap, а во втором у jccStick. Ну и id, да, они тоже отличаются

Comment: Что именно делает эта строчка `containerWRP.remove();` во второй функции? Не говрите что удаляет `containerWRP`. Откуда берётся сама эта переменная?  В первый раз вы показали что берёт его из DOM, а во втором случае?

Comment: Про цвет я имел ввиду знаечния одни и те же)

Comment: @EzioMercer, вот вот, я просто еще новичок, не совсем разобрался как работает добавление элементов. По этому и написал, как удалить, потому что правда не понимаю, и нагуглить что-то не смог((

Comment: Такс, давайте так. Вы отредактируете свой вопрос. Вставите две штуки минимально воспроизводимого кода (в конце должно быть 2 Code Snippet-a). Имеется ввиду без лишних вещей, без запросов, чисто код, создания и удаления элементов. Соотвественно при запуске первого кода мы должны увидеть, что удаляется нужный блок при клике, а при запуске второго кода мы должны увидеть, что вместо удаления, добавлеяется блок

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135804/discussion-between-daniil-and-eziomercer).

Answer (score -1):

function(e) - передаем параметр

let $parent = $(this).parent();
$parent.remove();